# Another term for "evenly contained subsets"

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, terminology

I was reading a paper and came across the term "even set" defined as follows: A set $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ is *even* if it is the disjoint union of intervals (of integers) of even length. Furthermore, a set $T$ is *evenly contained* in $S$ if $S\setminus T$ is even.

I've done some digging online and haven't been able to find much mention of this topic. I'm wondering if it has some other name.

For context, I'm interested in evenly contained subsets of $\{0,\dots,n\}$ which contain specific elements. Through investigation, I've found that there are $F_{n+2}$ ($n+2^{\text{nd}} $ Fibonacci number) evenly contained subsets of $\{0,\dots,n\}$.